# How to create a Circular Menu in Angular 10?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I wanted to create a circular menu that I came across on npmjs.com

As described, I used `npm install circular-menu` in order to install it.

After that, I added styles and scripts inside the "angular.json":

```
       "styles": [
                    "node_modules/circular-menu/dist/css/circular-menu.css",
                    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                    "src/styles.css"
                  ],
        "scripts": [
                    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                    "node_modules/circular-menu/dist/js/circular-menu.js"
                   ]
```

And then, I created a component using this command,  `ng g c Components/cir-comp`. If I want to paste the following code in my "cir-comp", how do I do that?

Mainly, I wanted to ask how to use the JavaScript code in my application?

```js
var menu = CMenu("#menu1")
  .config({
    menus: [{
      title: "GitHub",
      icon: "fa fa-github",
      href: {
        url: "http://github.com",
        blank: true
      }
    }, {
      title: "GitLab",
      icon: ["fa fa-gitlab", '#4078c0'],
    }, {
      title: "subMenu",
      icon: "my-icon icon1",
      menus: [{
        title: 'subMenu1',
        icon: 'fa fa-firefox'
      }, {
        title: 'subMenu2',
        icon: 'fa fa-file'
      }]
    }, {
      title: "subMenu",
      icon: "my-icon icon2"
    }, {
      title: "click",
      icon: "my-icon icon3"
    }, {
      title: "hash-href",
      href: "#someHash"
    }, {
      title: "clickMe!",
      click: function() {
        alert('click event callback');
      }
    }, {
      disabled: true,
      title: "disabled"
    }]
  });



$(document).click(function() {
  menu.hide();
});
$(document).contextmenu(function(e) {
  menu.show([e.pageX, e.pageY]);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.tips {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #999;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
}

.menu1 {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.my-icon {
  background: url("https://rawgit.com/yandongCoder/circular-menu/master/examples/circular-menu.png");
}

.icon1 {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.icon2 {
  background-position: 0 -56px;
}

.icon3 {
  background-position: 0 -116px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tips">
  Right click in page.
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="menu1">

</div>
```

I am trying to use the .js code inside "cir-comp.component.ts", but it just won't recognize the "CMenu". Could anybody tell me how do I use this code inside my component?

Here are the links:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-menu
2. https://jsfiddle.net/yandongCoder/kL4j7xor/10/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var menu = CMenu("#menu1")
  .config({
    menus: [{
      title: "GitHub",
      icon: "fa fa-github",
      href: {
        url: "http://github.com",
        blank: true
      }
    }, {
      title: "GitLab",
      icon: ["fa fa-gitlab", '#4078c0'],
    }, {
      title: "subMenu",
      icon: "my-icon icon1",
      menus: [{
        title: 'subMenu1',
        icon: 'fa fa-firefox'
      }, {
        title: 'subMenu2',
        icon: 'fa fa-file'
      }]
    }, {
      title: "subMenu",
      icon: "my-icon icon2"
    }, {
      title: "click",
      icon: "my-icon icon3"
    }, {
      title: "hash-href",
      href: "#someHash"
    }, {
      title: "clickMe!",
      click: function() {
        alert('click event callback');
      }
    }, {
      disabled: true,
      title: "disabled"
    }]
  });



$(document).click(function() {
  menu.hide();
});
$(document).contextmenu(function(e) {
  menu.show([e.pageX, e.pageY]);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.tips {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #999;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
}

.menu1 {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.my-icon {
  background: url("https://rawgit.com/yandongCoder/circular-menu/master/examples/circular-menu.png");
}

.icon1 {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.icon2 {
  background-position: 0 -56px;
}

.icon3 {
  background-position: 0 -116px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/yandongCoder/circular-menu/master/dist/css/circular-menu.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/yandongCoder/circular-menu/master/dist/js/circular-menu.js"></script>
<div class="tips">
  Right click in page.
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="menu1">

</div>
```

Add Jquery and the scripts and styles:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/yandongCoder/circular-menu/master/dist/css/circular-menu.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/yandongCoder/circular-menu/master/dist/js/circular-menu.js"></script>
```

UPDATE:

Add tsconfig.json file to project.

tsconfig.json:

```
{ "compilerOptions": { ..., "allowJs": true }
```

Try that.

Comment: I can't get .js code working in my "cir-comp.component.ts". How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to tell the typescript compiler `CMenu` exists. You can do this by adding the following line to the top of your ts file:

```
declare const CMenu: any
```

Comment: That took care of the `CMenu` but now I'm getting errors in this snippet: $(document).click(function() {
  menu.hide();
});
$(document).contextmenu(function(e) {
  menu.show([e.pageX, e.pageY]);
  return false;
});